# Loss of precision on adding doubles

Tags: c++

I have add the two **double number**.

```
double a=4.0;
double b=4.0;
cout<<a+b;
```

Answer is 8 only but required 8.0.

Comment: what precision have you lost?

Comment: Please be aware that 8.0 and 8 are the exact same numbers - they would have the same bitwise representation. They are indistinguishable. If you want to specify an *output format* that's a different matter.

Comment: but i have solve the hackerrank problem . where test case accept the 8.0 value not 8. he is not submit the answer

Comment: @BilalSiddiq I will repeat what already was said: you are having issue with specifying **output format**, and **not** with the actual precision of the number, as is suggested by the answer. In addition: if you can't understand what comments are saying, there's no need to tell us, that we don't know the answer.

Comment: Here is my code
int main()
{
    double d = 4.0;
    double doubleValue;
    cin>>doubleValue;
    cout<<d+doubleValue;
    return 0;
}

Comment: The problem is **not** the addition; all of the values involved can be exactly represented as floating-point values. The problem is in how you **display** the result.

Comment: the answer required 8.0 not 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is something like this:

```
cout << std::setprecision(1) << a+b;
```